# Why is QGIS 1.8 crashing when exporting to PDF?

Tags: qgis, export, osx

I want to export for example this:

[image]

but qgis crashes. Sometimes with an error message std::bad_alloc. But: My Mac has 8 GByte RAM and "just" 5,... something (of 8) GByte are used, moreover there is > 11 GByte free space on the disc.

Sometimes it crashes and you can have a look on an error report, like this one:

[image]

Now I noticed that everything works fine if I disclaim labels like "Unserer Lieben Frau". Is this a bug? It seems to be independent on the font used. Or... what can I do to export the results to PDF? Thanks a lot!!

Harald

Comment: Have your tired Apple's built-in PDF printer instead of QGIS'?  What do you mean your disclaim label?  Just adding a text field to the layout solves the issue?

Comment: @Harald do you mean you "uncheck" labels?

Comment: @Brad: Oh yes, you are right, I mean really to uncheck the labels. Sorry for the confusion....

Comment: @RomaH: Yes, it is possible to use the built-in PDF printer. But the quality is not so good. Because the pictures should be printed in a book I don't want to use this option

Comment: @Andre Joost: Thanks a lot for your hint. You are right, "new labelling" was the clue, everything is fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you used "old labelling" (from inside the layers properties) or "new labelling" (from the icon toolbar)? Old labelling is known to make problems.